Flatness of "derived local system sheaves"
Let $f: Y\longrightarrow X$ be a smooth proper map of smooth proper schemes over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\mathcal{F} = R^1_\text{ét}\overline{f}_*\mathbb{Q}_p$ denote the derived pushforward of $\overline{f}$, i.e. the sheaf with stalks $\mathcal{F}_x := H^1_\text{ét}(Y_x\otimes\overline{\mathbb{Q}}, \mathbb{Q}_p)$.
The local system $\mathcal{F}$ is smooth, and in particular flat, equipped with a $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$-action, which is unramified outside a finite set of primes $S$. Let $G_S$ denote the Galois group of the maximal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is unramified outside $S$, and let $\mathcal{G}$ denote the sheaf $H^1(G_S, \mathcal{F})$, whose value on a $G_S$-stable open $U$ is the group cohomology $H^1(G_S, \mathcal{F}(U))$ (is it a sheaf? I am fine with sheafifying if it isn't).
Question: is $\mathcal{G}$ flat? If not, are there reasonable assumptions one could add which would make it flat? Without assuming its action on the stalks is isomorphic everywhere.

This is going to be zero because the group cohomology in positive degrees of a finite group with coefficients in a characteristic zero vector space vanishes.

I didn't know that. My curiosity is specifically about Galois cohomology and I thought this variation might simplify the question so it may have more potential answers. I'll edit accordingly!

What do you mean by the $\mathbb Z_p$-rank of the stalks? The stalks will be finite $p$-groups. It might be better to ask a question based on exactly the situation you are interested in rather than trying to simplify.

I see. Corestriction of restriction with respect to the subgroup ${e}$ is both multiplication by $|G|$ and trivial. I corrected the question (again!) :)

Will Sawin was very nice to take your question at face value. I want to ask, though, and I don't mean this unkindly, do you have an advisor or a local expert you can get some guidance from? Your questions often suggest a basic unfamiliarity with how "things fit together" in arithmetic geometry.

Let me first give a simple answer to a related question: If you want to make a sheaf whose value at a point $x$ is $H^1( G_S, \mathcal F_x)$, this won't work and a useful such sheaf cannot be constructed.  This can be seen as for $Y\to X$ the universal family of elliptic curves, if you Tate twist the sheaf, you should pick up to Selmer group, which varies wildly in rank from one elliptic curve to the next, and thus can't be the stalks of a sheaf with any kind of flatness or constructibility property. If you don't Tate twist the sheaf, the stalks should all be $0$, so one can construct the sheaf but it won't be interesting.
A major subtlety here is that $p$-adic étale sheaves are not sheaves, at least not on the étale topology. Instead they are (equivalence classes of) inverse systems of mod $p^n$ sheaves for each $n$. For a "typical" locally constant $p$-adic sheaf $\mathcal F$, we have $\mathcal F(U)=0$ for all étale open sets $U$. This is rectified using the pro-étale topology of Bhatt and Scholze if you take pro-étale $U$.)
In fact your local system $\mathcal F$ is pure of weight $1$, so $\mathcal F(U)=0$ for all open sets $U$. However, you likely mean to take $K_S$ the maximal extension of $\mathbb Q$ ramified outside $S$ and consider $H^1(G_S, \mathcal F(U_{K_S}))$ since $\mathcal F(U_{K_S})$ admits a natural action of $G_S$.
The local system $\mathcal F$ has a maximal sub-local system $\mathcal G$ with finite geometric monodromy, and this local system $\mathcal G$ is geometrically constant. In particular there is some finite ètale cover $V$ over which $G$ becomes geometrically constant, i.e. isomorphic to some Galois representations $W$. Then for any étale open set $U$ lying over $V$, $\mathcal F(U_{K_S}) $ is the tensor product of $W$ with the permutation representation $P$ of $G_{K_s}$ on the geometrically connected components of $U$ defined over $K_S$. So the Galois cohomology will be $H^1( G_{K_s}, W \otimes P)$. If $U$ is connected then this permutation representation is transitive so this cohomology group will equal the cohomology of some open subgroup of $G_{K_s}$ with coefficients in $W$. I think this will be a sheaf, for the fundamental reason that the continuous cohomology of a profinite group $G$ with coefficients in a characteristic zero representation will agree with the $G/H$-invariants of the cohomology of $H$ with coefficients in the saem representation, where $H$ is the same open subgroup. The stalks will be the limit over all open subgroups $H$ of $H^1( H, W)$, which will either be $0$ if it vanishes for weight reasons or will (probably) be enormous.
Finally, we can say that your open sets $U$ are open in the pro-étale topology. In this case I think the sheafification should just vanish, because the subgroup need not be open and so you can pass to a small enough open set where you are taking the cohomology of the trivial group, but I'm less sure about that.
